# Cordova App - Azure MobileServiceClient not working properly on Android 5.x

Tags: cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, azure-mobile-services, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have troubles with a cordova app on my nexus 7(running Android 5.1.1).
The app uses the azure MobileServiceClient-Plugin(latest version) to connect to the azure-backend. Basic invokeApi-calls worked without problems on all devices/emulators tessted so far (Android 4.3, Windows Phone 8.1, windows 8.1, Ripple...).

However when i run the app on the 5.1.1-Tablet, all invokeApi-calls result in a 404 "Not found" response. The following snipped shows just 1 example call.

```
        connectusClient.invokeApi('CheckAuthToken', {
            method: 'GET'
        }).done(function () {
            success();
        }, function (error) {
            noSuccess();
        });
```

The only idea that i have is that the Android version leads to the problem.
Did anyone else face that problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

The getTable(...)-functions also result in 404.

Comment: The 404 is coming from a server.  In order to see what is going on, you'll have to get some sort of trace for the transaction is question.